# How to export a view to PDF in OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, pdf

In OS X 10.9, Apple introduced a simple way to export user content as PDF. The menu item called 'Export as PDF' is used to present a save sheet to export the data. (A example for this is Safari)
In its WWDC Videos Apple showed how it works, but my solution doesn't seem to be right. 
I am using a non-document based app.

I have managed to get the save sheet so far, but with my current code, I get the print sheet as well after that. Furthermore, no data is saved so far.

Here is my code:

```
NSPrintOperation* printOP = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:_textView];
printOP.printInfo.jobDisposition = NSPrintSaveJob;
[printOP runOperationModalForWindow:_window 
                           delegate:nil didRunSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From **NSView Class Reference**:

[**dataWithPDFInsideRect:**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/dataWithPDFInsideRect:)
Returns PDF data that draws the region of the receiver within a specified rectangle.